# Overlayed plots without shared axes: left-bottom vs. top-right pairs (python/matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Python/Matplotlib, how can I have two plots on the same graph that DO NOT share any axis? i.e., a first plot uses the left and bottom axes, and the second plot uses the top and right axes. Each pair of axes is independent, and would be used to draw several curves independently but on the same graph.
For example, this is typically used for a biplot of a Principal Component Analysis.

As far as I can tell, my solution is NOT through `twinx` or `twiny`, and I haven't been able to find a solution with `host_suplot` neither... and all my researches lead me to solutions with a shared axis, which do not address this particular situation.
Thanks.

Comment: look at how `tvinx` acts under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very elegant, but it works.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(10)
y1 = x1**2
x2 = np.arange(100,200)
y2 = x2

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], label="ax1")
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], label="ax2", frameon=False)

ax1.yaxis.tick_left()
ax1.xaxis.tick_bottom()


ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
ax2.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

ax1.spines['right'].set_color('red')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('red')

for ylabel, xlabel in zip(ax2.get_yticklabels(), ax2.get_xticklabels()):
     ylabel.set_color("red")
     xlabel.set_color("red")


ax1.plot(x1,y1)
ax2.plot(x2,y2, 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks exactly right.  To make it 'elegant' hide it in a function ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot @M4rtini, it perfectly does the job - in the absence of built-in immediate solution, I am very happy with yours. [Sorry, I can't vote]

Comment: No problem :) You should be able to accept the answer even though you can't vote.